# How to call external REST webservices inside Liferay portlet?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a web app that exposes REST webservices.
I want to call those web services using javascript\jQuery (ajax)
Basically I want to render the contents returned by the REST service & perform CRUD openations (which will call other REST services of the external web app)

Anyone has some pointers, articles, sample code that shows how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that your question is too generic and abstract. You'll need to be more specific and provide more information like 1) What kind of Portlet are you using (MVC/Spring/JSF/Struts), 2) Do need help to make the portlet communicate with the REST service, OR with the whole request-controller chain? Maybe you need help to decide which libraries to use 3) Wouldn't hurt giving us a Liferay version

Comment: 1) The portlet will be developed using LDS (Liferay Developer Studio) using spring 2) Yes. Portlet should communicate with external REST service by calling them via Ajax 3) Library will be jQuery or pure javascript 4) Liferay version is 6.1.30

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, there's nothing Liferay-specific in calling external webservices, so you can use any tutorial you find on the web. As you're mentioning you want to use jquery, I assume that those calls will be made from the browser - the only thing that you need to do in Liferay is to make sure that jquery is loaded - for this you can use your theme: Edit `portal-normal.vm` and include the line to load jquery. Alternatively, as Liferay comes with AlloyUI/YUI, you can load jQuery as a module for AUI with its module [yQuery](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/yquery)

Comment: I will be using view.jsp to drop the calls to REST services. It seems a workable solution.

Comment: yeah, but just because you place it on a portlet, there's no technical difference to making the call - it works just as if you're calling out from a non-portlet resource.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code using javascript\jQuery to call REST webservices inside portlet (Call Portal Service with Basic Authorization Header):

```
                <%@ include file="init.jsp"%>
                
                
                $(document).on('ready',function(){
                        var username ="test@liferay.com";
                        var password ="test"; 
                        function make_base_auth(user, password) {
                          var tok = user + ':' + password;
                          var hash = btoa(tok);
                          return "Basic " + hash;
                        }
                            $.ajax({
                              url: 'http://localhost:8080/LiferayJSONWebservices-portlet/api/jsonws/employee/get-employee/employee-id/1',
                              dataType: "json",
                              type: "get",
                              success: function(data){
                                      alert(data.employeeName);
                              },
                              beforeSend: function(xhr){ xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',make_base_auth(username, password));
                                                },
                                                complete: function(){
                                                },
                              error: function(){
                              }
                            });
```

```
            });
            </script>
```